# How to play/decode Ogg Opus Audio in Safari?

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-audio, web-audio-api, opus

OGG Opus audio format is not supported in Safari. Are there any high-level (decoding?) libraries that make .ogg files playable in Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, finally I found the `opus-recorder` module. Here is a nice example of how to decode `Opus -> PCM -> WAV` and play it: https://github.com/chris-rudmin/opus-recorder/blob/master/example/decoder.html. Works like a charm in Safari.

Answer (score -1):

You should just have fallback for browsers that don't support it. If you'd like to take a more complex approach [this](https://github.com/brion/ogv.js/) is always an option.

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="audio.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Not an option for me, unfortunately. I need to encode on the fly.